# How can I make a modal cover the status bar?

Tags: ios, modal-dialog

I've been searching for a while now but I just can't seem to get this right, I just want my full screen modal to cover the status bar.

This is the closes I've gotten:
[image]

I'm just using `[[UIApplication shared..] setStatusbarHidden:YES ...]`

Anyone?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have done so far? Have you tried any of the following solutions in: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2188401/558933 . If so, what do they not do correctly?

Comment: The one I have now makes the status bar pop away after presented. The ones in that answer (and tweaks) makes the status bar dissapear, shifting the view up. I want my main view (in the gif: money log) and its status bar to be stationary while the modal animates/presents OVER it, i.e. covering it.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't think the status bar is part of any frame in your app and so a bounds of `(0, 0)` won't cover it. All I can think of is set clipping to `NO` and set a frame for `Expense Income` in your `UINavigationBar` of (0, -20). I don't know how Apple's Notifications handle this - presumably they're in a different `UIWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

In the class of your modal view controller implement:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

This will cause the status bar to be automatically hidden whenever that UIViewController appears. Present it as normal and it will hide the status bar.

You may also need to set modalViewController.view.backgroundColor.

Comment: I've tried this, using both "View controller-based status bar appearance" (in the plist) as YES and NO.

Comment: Try setting the background color of the UIViewController's view?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you mean to "hide" the status bar text? (e.g. make it blend). That's not an option, as the header will have different, non-white, colors.